# which version of adb interface for android "nexus 7" 2013

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, driver, nexus-7

developing an app for the 2013 nexus 7 with android studio on windows 8.1. i have the app running on a few different devices. when adding a driver, i get a dialog:

[image: update driver dialog]

with the clockwork mod manufacturer, i get other choices like: google nexus 7 adb interface version 7.0.0.1 or 7.0.0.4.

i assume that i want an adb interface or a composite one, but sometimes there are many choices.

which interface should i use for the 2013 nexus 7?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the OEM USB Drives from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html).

Android Composite interface is higher level interface that includes Android ADB (Android Debug Bridge) interface, Android MTP (Media Transfer Protocol), PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol), Mass Storage Protocol etc.

I think you can go forward with ADB Interfere v8 as it's backward compatible.

Make the choice as per your requirment.

Comment: Updated the link again :)

Comment: asus page does not seem to have a driver and i am currently stuck on getting any driver to load: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060989/android-2013-nexus-7-and-windows-8-1-x-64-drivers

Comment: @RayTayek, You don't basically need ASUS Driver for Nexus device, Google OEM drivers will do. if you still have problem check with the driver provided by ASUS here : https://www.asus.com/Tablets/Nexus_7/HelpDesk_Download/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the newest ADB driver fine.
But if you are having problems picking the device up in Android Studio, then make sure you have the device connected using the correct protocol.

Usually you have the choice between `Media (MTP)` or `Camera (PTP)`.

This can vary between devices but use whichever one works for you, and makes the device appear in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You should download and install the driver from Google

https://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

The CWM ones may work, but the Google drivers are the officially supported drivers for the Nexus 7

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pdanet](http://pdanet.co/) if you are using mac or windows.
it supports most of the devices for debugging and is really helpful for some country based manufacturers.